# How do I remove JSON form JSON array with repeated key-value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, arraylist

I have a JSON as follows:

```
[{"name": "John", "id": 1},
 {"name": "Don", "id": 2},
 {"name": "Tom", "id": 3},
 {"name": "NewJohn", "id": 1},
 {"name": "Tim", "id": 4}]
```

I want to first identify if key "id" has same value. If yes, I want to remove previous JSON with the same "id" so that I get following JSON with unique "id" values in the JSON Array.

```
[{"name": "Don", "id": 2},
 {"name": "Tom", "id": 3},
 {"name": "NewJohn", "id": 1},
 {"name": "Tim", "id": 4}]
```

How do I achieve this in javascript?

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduceRight` to start loop from the end and add to new array if there wasn't element with same id.

```js
var data = [{"name": "John", "id": 1}, {"name": "Don", "id": 2}, {"name": "Tom", "id": 3}, {"name": "NewJohn", "id": 1}, {"name": "Tim", "id": 4}]
 
var result = [] 
data.reduceRight(function(r, e) {
  if(!r[e.id]) {
    result.unshift(e);
    r[e.id] = 1;
  }
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yep, the question is trickier than it seems, and reduceRight seems to do the trick... if possible, could you _please_ remove the comma operator? ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Use Following code. This will solve your problem**

```js
    var obj = [{"name": "John", "id": 1}, {"name": "Don", "id": 2}, {"name": "Tom", "id": 3}, {"name": "NewJohn", "id": 1}, {"name": "Tim", "id": 4}];
        var seenNames = {};
    
    obj = obj.reverse().filter(function(currentObject) {
        if (currentObject.id in seenNames) {
            return false;
        } else {
            seenNames[currentObject.id] = true;
            return true;
        }
    });
    
    console.log(obj)
```

Comment: But this will give only those objects that are required. Can you be more specific...

Comment: Just compare their output to yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=new Map(data.map(el=>[el.id,el]));
```

You may create a Map out of it.. which can be destructured to an array:

```
result=[...result].map(e=>e[1]);
```

http://jsbin.com/zuqabonebe/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

Using two for loop I delete the previous id property.

```js
var data=[{"name": "John", "id": 1},
 {"name": "Don", "id": 2},
 {"name": "Tom", "id": 3},
 {"name": "NewJohn", "id": 1},
 {"name": "Tim", "id": 4}];

function deleteJsonProperty(dataJson){
for(var i=0;i<dataJson.length;i++){  
  for(var z=i+1;z<dataJson.length;z++){
  if(dataJson[i].id===dataJson[z].id){
    delete dataJson[i].id;
  }
  }
}
  return dataJson;
}
console.log(deleteJsonProperty(data));
```